# useAsyncEffect not being called when state changed in sibling

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to prompt a useAsyncEffect call when changing a state in a sibling?

I have a dashboard:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import PageHeader from "../components/PageHeader"
import StudentResults from "../components/StudentResults"
import StudentList from "../components/StudentList"



const  Dashboard = () => {

  const [selectedStudent, setSelectedStudent] = useState(null)

  console.log('Set on Dashboard: ', selectedStudent)
  

  return (
  <div className="dashboard">
    <h1 className="page-title">Assessment Platform</h1>
    <div className="page-header">
      <PageHeader />
    </div>
    <div className="dashboard-body">
      <StudentList setSelectedStudent={setSelectedStudent}/>
      <div className="student-results-container">
        <StudentResults selectedStudent={selectedStudent}/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="page-footer">
      Page Footer
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Which renders a list of students:

```
import { useState, Fragment } from 'react'
import useAsyncEffect from 'use-async-effect'

const StudentList = ({setSelectedStudent, selectedStudent}) => {

  const [students, setStudents] = useState(null)

  useAsyncEffect(async isMounted => {
    try {
      const userEmail = 'western-sydney@email.com'
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/studentlistbyuser/${userEmail}`)
      const json = await response.json()
      if (!isMounted()) return
      setStudents(json)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
  }, [])
  
return (
    <div className="student-list-container">
        <div className="student-list">
          <div className="student-list-table-header">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style={{ width: '15%'}}>Student ID</th>
                  <th style={{ width: '30%'}}>Student Name</th>
                  <th style={{ width: '25%'}}>Student Class</th>
                  <th style={{ width: '15%'}}>Accademic Year</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div className="student-list-table-body">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                {students && students.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                      <Fragment key={i}>
                        <tr onClick={(e) => setSelectedStudent(item.studentid)}>
                         <td style={{ width: '15%'}}>{item.studentid}</td>
                         <td style={{ width: '30%'}}>{item.studentname}</td>
                         <td style={{ width: '25%'}}>{item.classname}</td>
                         <td style={{ width: '15%'}}>{item.accademicyear}</td>
                       </tr>
                      </Fragment>
                    )
                  })}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
)
}

export default StudentList
```

Along side this is a StudentResults. When you click on a student in the StudentList the results should refresh for the `selectedStudent`

```
import StudentResultItem from "./StudentResultItem"
import { useState } from 'react'
import useAsyncEffect from 'use-async-effect'

const StudentResults = ({selectedStudent}) => {
    
    console.log('Passed to Student Results: ', selectedStudent)
    const [results, setResults] = useState(null)

    useAsyncEffect(async isMounted => {

        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/GetStudentResults/${selectedStudent}`)
            const json = await response.json()
            if (!isMounted()) return
            setResults(json)
            console.log(json)
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
                {results && results.map((result, _index) => (<StudentResultItem key={_index} result={result} />))}
            </div>

        </div>
        

    )
    }
    
    export default StudentResults
```

The problem I am having is that the `selectedStudent` gets passed to StudentResults  each time I click on a student, but the `useAsyncEffect` in StudentResults does not trigger.

I am new and self taught, any direction much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to add the `selectedStudent` prop to the deps array of `useAsyncEffect` like `useAsyncEffect(() => {}, [selectedStudent])`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this, the solution as detailed in a comment on the question is very simple:

Add the `selectedStudent` prop to the dep array of `useAsyncEffect`

```
useAsyncEffect(async isMounted => {

        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/GetStudentResults/${selectedStudent}`)
            const json = await response.json()
            if (!isMounted()) return
            setResults(json)
            console.log(json)
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
    }, [selectedStudent])
```